# Angular:- value defined in one component use it in another component using services

Tags: angular, typescript

I created service to share data between two components, I read documentation and checked few articles but couldn't understand it properly and stuck.

I created the stackblitz to learn as a sample for data sharing. Here's the link
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-footer)

So below is my code 
footer.component.ts

```
//trying to set value here 
    test(){
            let height:any;
            this.footerHeightService.setFooterHeight(height) 
           height = document.getElementById("footer").offsetTop;
        }
```

footer-height.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


    @Injectable()
    export class FooterHeightService {


    footerOffset:any;
      constructor() { }

      setFooterHeight(height){
        this.footerOffset = height;
      }

      getFooterHeight(height){
        return this.footerOffset;
      }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
//trying to get value here 
     constructor(private footerHeightService:FooterHeightService) { }

       test(){
        let height:any;
        this.footerHeightService.getFooterHeight(height);
        console.log("this.footerHeightService.getFooterHeight(height);", height);
      }


      ngOnInit():void{
        this.test();
      }
```

Comment: You can utilise `input` , `output` modules

Comment: its not parent child components. I think input, output is used for parent and child components

Comment: You are including footer in all the component, so why cant you use `input` , `output`

Comment: It was a sample to understand the data sharing using devices in stuck in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need to create a service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  constructor() { }
  dataShared: any

  setFooterData(data) {
    this.dataShared = data
  }
  getFooterData() {
    return this.dataShared
  }

}
```

And in your component footer, you will send the data to the service by calling its method set

```
constructor(
 ...
 private sharedService: SharedServiceService
) { }

componentMethod() {
  this.sharedService.setFooterData(data)
}
```

And in the component app, you will get the data by calling the get method

```
constructor(
 ...
 private sharedService: SharedServiceService
) { }

componentMethod() {
      this.sharedService.getFooterData()
}
```

[live code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-share-service)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification 

Comment: In your `test` method of your footer component, you're setting an undefined data `height`. Consider assigning a value to it before setting the value of the service. It should be `height = document.getElementById("footer").offsetTop; this.footerHeightService.setFooterHeight(height)`. Also, please see the way I defined the get method of the service without parameter

Comment: can you check I updated it I followed tour instructions seems still missing something

Comment: still undefined I fixed the things which you told

Comment: The child component needs to set the value before the parent retrieves it. That is why I used a timeout

Comment: can we do it without child-parent relationship? The components which I am working have no parent-child relationship at all. the stakcblitz was just a sample to learn data sharing with services

Comment: The simple thing to keep in mind is that the method of the child needs to be called before that of the parent. Of course, one can achieve the same thing without the relation parent child

Comment: can you update the live demo with that? Like when I used <app-footer></app-footer> it blow up the error then I realize its just because it doesnt have any relationship